# Firebase web v9 upgrade breaks react-firebase-hooks "useCollectionData()"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update some Firebase code in a React project to the [new modular web v9 sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) that Firebase released recently. The project being upgraded uses the [react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore) hook `useCollectionData()`, which fails upon changing to the new sdk. I get the following error output in my console 3 times when I try to run my ported code.

> index.esm.js:101 Uncaught TypeError: v1.isEqual is not a function

A minimal example of working web v8 code:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import { useCollectionData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore"


firebase.initializeApp({ //config here
})
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

function Foo() {
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages')
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25)
  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' })

  return (<> {messages} </>)
}
```

My attempt at porting to v9 that causes the error:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { useCollectionData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore"


const app = initializeApp({ //config here
})
const db = getFirestore(app)

function Foo() {
  const messagesRef = collection(db, "messages")
  const q = query(messagesRef, orderBy("createdAt"), limit(25))
  const [messages] = useCollectionData(q, { idField: "id" })
  
  return (<> {messages} </>)
}
```

I'm upgrading my dependencies from

```json
"dependencies" : {
  "firebase": "^7.20.0",
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "react-firebase-hooks": "^2.2.0",
}
```

to

```json
"dependencies" : {
  "firebase": "^9.0.2",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "react-firebase-hooks": "^3.0.4",
}
```

[This Firestore doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) has examples I used to write my updated code. I also used [this Firestore doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#collection) to better understand the changes to `collection()`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update 3 Nov 2021:

[React Firebase Hooks v4](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/releases/tag/v4.0.0) has been released which supports v9 and also requires React 16.8.0 or later and Firebase v9.0.0 or later.

---

The [React Firebase Hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks) library doesn't seem to support Firebase Modular SDK yet (last release April 2021). You might have to use `compat` version which allows to use older name-spaced syntax even in `v9.0.0+` and does not have benefits of tree-shaking :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
// import 'firebase/compat/[SERVICE_NAME]'
```