# how to use react-firebase-hooks in firebase web v9

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am using 'react-firebase-hooks',  firebase web v9. I have this error : " TypeError: *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.db.collection is not a function"

This is the code causing the issue:

```js
import { useCollection } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

const [realtimePosts, loading, error] = useCollection(
  db.collection('posts').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase web v9 upgrade breaks react-firebase-hooks "useCollectionData()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242511/firebase-web-v9-upgrade-breaks-react-firebase-hooks-usecollectiondata)

Answer (score 0):

Checking the `react-firebase-hooks` [home page](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks), it appears there is no support yet for the Firebase modular SDK (V9), like the comment refers:

> This documentation is for v3 of React Firebase Hooks which involved a number of breaking changes, including adding support for Firebase v8.0.0 - more details here. For v2 documentation, see here.

Looking through the repository issues, it seems that a [pull request](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/pull/174) that would include support for Firebase V9 has not been merged yet, so using the previous SDK would be the solution until the release is out.